# Extended PageSize Information in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I have to print a custom label to a thermal printer.  I have everything setup and working with one exception: the rolls of labels have two labels per row, but the C# printing objects can't seem to see that.

When I query the PageSize information, it tells me that the label is 3.15" x 0.75".  While this is true *for the entire label*, it doesn't give me any information about the size of each individual label, or the spacing between.

Digging into the driver ini files, there is a line that looks like `PageSize84 = THT-6-423,3150,2,1500,750,150,125,1`.  All of the information I need seems to be listed in this line (2 columns, 1500 wide, 750 tall), I just have no idea how to access it from C#.  I've been scouring the web today, and I've had no luck.

I could always hard code the information for now, but this doesn't future proof the code if manufacturing changes labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to read an ini file to get the values you can use this.

IniFile.ReadIniValue("[Tag]", "Server", @"C:\my.ini");

```
#region Usings

using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Communicates with ini files
/// </summary>
public static class IniFile
{
    #region Declarations



    #endregion

    #region Constructor/Deconstructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IniFile"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static IniFile()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties



    #endregion

    #region Win32_API

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(
        string section,
        string key, string def,
        StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName,
       string lpKeyName, string lpString, string lpFileName);

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the ini value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="section">The section.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="iniFilePath">The ini file path.</param>
    /// <returns>Value stored in key</returns>
    /// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException"></exception>
    public static string ReadIniValue(string section, string key, string iniFilePath)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(iniFilePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        const int size = 255;
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(size);
        var len = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, string.Empty, buffer, size, iniFilePath);

        if (len > 0)
        {
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the ini value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="section">The section.</param>
    /// <param name="keyname">The keyname.</param>
    /// <param name="valueToWrite">The value to write.</param>
    /// <param name="iniFilePath">The ini file path.</param>
    /// <returns>true if write was successful, false otherwise</returns>
    public static bool WriteIniValue(string section,string keyname,string valueToWrite,string iniFilePath)
    {
        return WritePrivateProfileString(section, keyname, valueToWrite, iniFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up having to hard code the path to the ini file, which I don't like, but the rest works now.

Comment: Depending on where your ini file is you could possibly use Environment.SpecialFolder to make it more dynamic.